# Best practices for multiple table joins UNION vs JOIN

Tags: sql, join, union

I'm using a query which brings ~74 fields from different database tables.

- The query consists of 10 FULL JOINS and 15 LEFT JOINS.
- Each join condition is based on different fields.

The query fetches data from a main table which contains almost 90% foreign keys.
I'm using those joins for the foreign keys but some of the data doesn't require those joins because it's type of data(as logic) doesn't use those information.

Let me give an example:
Each employee can have multiple Tasks.There are four types of tasks(1,2,3,4).
Each TaskType has different meaning. When running the query , I'm getting data for all those tasktypes and then do some logic for showing them separately.

My question is : It is better to use UNION ALL and split all the 4 different cases into queries? This way I could use only the required joins for each case in each union.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you will have to run some benchmarks to get an answer.

Comment: ["Which is faster?"](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) questions are very difficult to answer, especially if you do not include any code, or table structures. The answer is going to depend on too many factors to give a straight answer based on a few sentences.

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Performance tuning **highly** depends on the DBMS

Comment: I'm using SQL server

Comment: 10 full joins?! I would like to see that query. It is rare to see even one full join.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it depends strongly on the size (row number count) of the main table an e.g. the task tables.

Say if your main table has tens of millions of rows and the tasks are smaller, then a union with all tasks will necessitate table scans every time, whereas a join with the smaller task tables can do this with one table scan.